# How to filter data by month and year in Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to filter the daily data by month and year. For instance, it will show the daily sales on a daily basis in only January 2020 and January 2021.

```
SELECT date, sum(sales) as sales
FROM X
WHERE date = ('2020-01') and date = ('2021-01')
GROUP BY 1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You probably meant `or` and not `and` in your WHERE cluase

Answer (score 1):

Date format seems to be problem.
Can you try something like this?

```
SELECT date, sum(sales) as sales
FROM X
WHERE time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01' AND TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: thanks, this solved my question: DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M') = 'January'

Comment: Happy to hear that, date format was the problem as you've identified :)